# Which operating system to prepare for RHCSA

Tags: linux, centos, rhel

On which operating should you focus the most for RHCSA? I know CentOS is literally a free copy of RedHat OS however is it really the same or are there some things that are done different, than in RedHat? Is it better to use evaluation copy of RedHat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say it doesn't really matter for the RHCSA.

The two operating systems are almost identical expect for branding

The things you will be tested on in the RHCSA you can learn on either OS. You wont be at a disadvantage on one or the other. Just make sure you have gone through the course syllabus and learnt everything you need for the exam.

A good website for training is: https://linuxacademy.com/ ....you also get access to a VM with the latest red hat release to do the labs.

Comment: Do you think it is worth of getting a yearly access to RedHat learning center or linuxacademy will be just fine with the proper books?

Comment: You can pass the exam with just books. You need to put in the effort...and practice practical scenarios. The thing i like about Linux academy is they have a lot of other training materials on there...loads of courses....AWS,google cloud,big data, DevOps courses... just to name a few, i think for the money it is well worth it. I know multiple people who have passed the RHSCA just by using Linux Academy course.

Comment: What do you think about official RedHat Training center. It is crazy expensive but is it actually worth it?

Comment: I have no experience with it. I can only speak for what i have used and others i know......you can pass the exam without RedHat training center.  Whatever you choose to help you...you just need to study study study! :)

Comment: I know that you have to put lots of effort. I have done my Cisco certs is well and it takes a good amount of time to learn everything properly. Is Linux Academy covering every part of the exam? Do you know if they update the videos if something has been change in the exam?

Comment: Yeah it covers everything you could face in the exam, you still need to practice though. Yes they change the course if the exam changes...the course you will be studying is RHCSA 7... the course will be different for redhat 8 whenever that comes out....

Comment: Thank you all for the hints. It's a time to order books, get some online course and start studying for it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75910/discussion-between-mrktos-and-declan-gallagher).

Answer (score 2):

CentOS is compiled from the same source code as RedHat, only trademarked graphics (etc.) are replaced with CentOS versions. So all the functional parts and procedures are exactly the same.

For RHCSA and RHCE, there should be no difference. At the RHCA level, it depends on which component certifications you're seeking: some components might be inconvenient to get as free versions.